# Generic Data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Create a generic data class which has one variable data Type

```kotlin
data class <T> GenericResponse(
  val success: Boolean,
  val message: String,
  val data: T
)
```

To use it: `GenericResponse<SomeOtherDataClass>`

How to do this in kotlin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the `<T>` after the class name:

```kotlin
data class GenericResponse<T>(
  val success: Boolean,
  val message: String,
  val data: T
)
```